# Write to existing named pipe via Python

Tags: python, bash, pipe

I have a named pipe, created in Bash as follows:

```
PIPE_IN=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo $PIPE_IN
```

This produces, for example: /tmp/tmp.H8EP7rYjCL

How do I write to this named pipe in Python?
I've tried re-opening this as a file:

```
with open('/tmp/tmp.H8EP7rYjCL', 'w') as f:
    f.write('something')
```

but that doesn't work.  Oddly, it seems that whatever I write to the newly opened file gets buffered internally.  When I write to the named pipe via Bash, I see the buffered content in the process attached to the named pipe.  For example,

```
echo "foo" > /tmp/tmp.H8EP7rYjCL
```

yields

```
somethingfoo
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What happens, and what did you expect to happen?  Note that when you open a named pipe for reading or writing, that `open()` call blocks until another process opens the other end of the pipe; see [`mkfifo(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either flush the pipe or write a newline (which will usually flush automatically. This is what echo does, incidentially. Also read from the pipe before you kill the python process; otherwise it may be blocked on writing on the pipe.

Edit: Forget about flushing (see comment below).

Comment: close() also does flushing, unless an I/O error happens.

Comment: Thanks!  Writing a newline did the trick.  By the way, I tried close(), but it didn't flush.  I also tried flush(), and it didn't do anything.  But writing a newline did!